# I want to get the '' Alice " value from the parsed JSON in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

I want to print Alice from this passed JSON as dict from views to the HTML file.

this is my view file

`result = json.loads(JSON_DATA.content)`

`return render(request, 'home.html', {'result' : result})`

[This is the JSON Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y6Uy.png)

`{`

```
    "firstName" : "Jane",
    "lastName" : "Dow",
    "hobbiles" : ["running", "sky diving", "singing"],
    "age" :  35,
    "children" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "Alice",
            "age" : 6,
        }, 
        {
            "firstName" : "Bob",
            "age" : 8,
        }
    ]
}
```

here is what I tried in  HTML template

`{{ result.children[0].firstName }}`

this throws an error 
*** TemplateSyntaxError*** 
could not parse remainder '[0].firstName' from 'result.children[0].firstName'

how can I access the value in HTML template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `result.children[0].firstName`

---

please use this syntax `result.children.0.firstName`